# How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm using the Laravel Eloquent query builder and I have a query where I want a `WHERE` clause on multiple conditions. It works, but it's not elegant.

Example:

```php
$results = User::where('this', '=', 1)
    ->where('that', '=', 1)
    ->where('this_too', '=', 1)
    ->where('that_too', '=', 1)
    ->where('this_as_well', '=', 1)
    ->where('that_as_well', '=', 1)
    ->where('this_one_too', '=', 1)
    ->where('that_one_too', '=', 1)
    ->where('this_one_as_well', '=', 1)
    ->where('that_one_as_well', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

Is there a better way to do this, or should I stick with this method?

Comment: There are many possibilities in terms of how this could be simplified, but that would require some more realistic code. Can you update the code to be a little more realistic? For example, there are times when multiple `->where(...)` calls can be replaced by a `->whereIn(...)` call, *et cetera*.

Comment: The @Jarek Tkaczyk's solution should be the answer, I agree. But I'd prefer your code like builder script for comprehension and maintenance.

Comment: Hope this link will be helpful to the future users in-depth multiple where condition example: https://www.scratchcode.io/laravel-multiple-where-conditions-with-example/

Comment: laravel requiring the first call to be static but the rest -> is really bad design.

Comment: @paresh-mangukiya please stop adding spurious tags to old questions. They are not helpful.

Comment: For anyone seeing this after 2022, Laravel's query builder documentation has examples for [Advanced](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#advanced-where-clauses) and [Basic](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#basic-where-clauses) WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 898, accepted):

**In [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)** (and still true as of [7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses)) you can use more granular wheres passed as an array:

```
$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])
```

Personally I haven't found use-case for this over just multiple `where` calls, but fact is you can use it.

**Since June 2014 you can pass an array to `where`**

As long as you want all the `wheres` use `and` operator, you can group them this way:

```
$matchThese = ['field' => 'value', 'another_field' => 'another_value', ...];

// if you need another group of wheres as an alternative:
$orThose = ['yet_another_field' => 'yet_another_value', ...];
```

Then:

```
$results = User::where($matchThese)->get();

// with another group
$results = User::where($matchThese)
    ->orWhere($orThose)
    ->get();
```

The above will result in such query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE (field = value AND another_field = another_value AND ...)
  OR (yet_another_field = yet_another_value AND ...)
```

Comment: How do you specify the operator?

Comment: @Styphon You don't. Currently it work only with `=`.

Comment: @Styphon and what if i want to make:
```WHERE (a IS NOT NULL AND b=1) OR (a IS NULL AND b=2);```
?

Comment: Is this supported in Laravel 4 or only in 5 and further?

Comment: You can also pass an array of conditions like this: ```$users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status', '=', '1'],
    ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();```

Comment: No need for "=" . Also there is whereColumn( [ ] ) works perfect .

Comment: @jarek : How do I include the `whereNotIn` according to your answer with having other `where` cluases?

Comment: @Kalanka show a paste of your sql, or pseudo-code you'd like to run, because I can't guess what you mean ;)

Comment: @jarek: assume i have a table of fields as id,name,type,policy and age.here is the query  : `$data=$this->model->where('name','=',$name)->where('type','=',$type)->whereNotIn('policy',$policy)->pluck('id')`

Comment: @Kalanka so basically `where([ .. array of conditions like name, type etc])->whereNotIn('policy', $policies)`, nothing fancy here

Comment: How can I use raw statement with this example? Something like `datetime >= now()`

Comment: Do you can omit using the `COMPARATOR` when is equal? `->where(['status', '1'])` or you can't omit it when using where like that?

Comment: Please note that this will only add `AND` in `WHERE` clause. If you need `OR` condition please use `orWhere()`

Comment: I don't understand why Laravel documentation does not document things like `orWhere`, `orWhereIn` etc?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, may I ask you to have a look at a Laravel search related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485513/laravel-search-with-multiple-keywords-against-multiple-columns-with-the-search ?

Answer (score 140):

You can use subqueries in anonymous function like this:

```
 $results = User::where('this', '=', 1)
       ->where('that', '=', 1)
       ->where(
           function($query) {
             return $query
                    ->where('this_too', 'LIKE', '%fake%')
                    ->orWhere('that_too', '=', 1);
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Could you please link to the documentation for the likes of `orWhere`? I couldnt find it.

Comment: Here you are: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries "If you would like to use a "where" clause on your joins, you may use the where and orWhere methods provided by the JoinClause instance..."

Answer (score 123):

Query scopes may help you to let your code more readable.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Updating this answer with some example:

In your model, create scopes methods like this:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', '=', 1);
}

public function scopeThat($query)
{
    return $query->where('that', '=', 1);
}
```

Then, you can call this scopes while building your query:

```
$users = User::active()->that()->get();
```

Comment: what is the best practice for a condition like this,
 query->where('start_date' > $startDate)
is it still okay to use Scopes?

Answer (score 82):

**Conditions using Array:**

```
$users = User::where([
       'column1' => value1,
       'column2' => value2,
       'column3' => value3
])->get();
```

***Will produce query like below:***

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column1 = value1 and column2 = value2 and column3 = value3
```

**Conditions using Anonymous Function:**

```
$users = User::where('column1', '=', value1)
               ->where(function($query) use ($variable1,$variable2){
                    $query->where('column2','=',$variable1)
                   ->orWhere('column3','=',$variable2);
               })
              ->where(function($query2) use ($variable1,$variable2){
                    $query2->where('column4','=',$variable1)
                   ->where('column5','=',$variable2);
              })->get();
```

***Will produce query like below:***

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column1 = value1 and (column2 = value2 or column3 = value3) and (column4 = value4 and column5 = value5)
```

Answer (score 57):

In this case you could use something like this:

```
User::where('this', '=', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('created_at')
    ->whereNotNull('updated_at')
    ->where(function($query){
        return $query
        ->whereNull('alias')
        ->orWhere('alias', '=', 'admin');
    });
```

It should supply you with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` 
WHERE `user`.`this` = 1 
    AND `user`.`created_at` IS NOT NULL 
    AND `user`.`updated_at` IS NOT NULL 
    AND (`alias` IS NULL OR `alias` = 'admin')
```

Answer (score 19):

```
Model::where('column_1','=','value_1')
       ->where('column_2 ','=','value_2')
       ->get();
```

OR

```
// If you are looking for equal value then no need to add =
Model::where('column_1','value_1')
        ->where('column_2','value_2')
         ->get();
```

OR

```
Model::where(['column_1' => 'value_1',
              'column_2' => 'value_2'])->get();
```

Comment: Great stuff.. Thanks @DsRaj

Answer (score 15):

**Multiple where clauses**

```
    $query=DB::table('users')
        ->whereRaw("users.id BETWEEN 1003 AND 1004")
        ->whereNotIn('users.id', [1005,1006,1007])
        ->whereIn('users.id',  [1008,1009,1010]);
    $query->where(function($query2) use ($value)
    {
        $query2->where('user_type', 2)
            ->orWhere('value', $value);
    });

   if ($user == 'admin'){
        $query->where('users.user_name', $user);
    }
```

**finally getting the result**

```
    $result = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 10):

The `whereColumn` method can be passed an array of multiple conditions. These conditions will be joined using the `and` operator.

**Example:**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereColumn([
                ['first_name', '=', 'last_name'],
                ['updated_at', '>', 'created_at']
            ])->get();

$users = User::whereColumn([
                ['first_name', '=', 'last_name'],
                ['updated_at', '>', 'created_at']
            ])->get();
```

For more information check this section of the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 9):

**Multiple Where**

- You may also pass an array of conditions to the where function. Each element of the array should be an array containing the three arguments typically passed to the where method:

```php
Model::where([
    ['status', '=', '1'],
    ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();
```

**Multiple Or Where Clauses**

- If you need to group an "or" condition within parentheses, you may pass a closure as the first argument to the orWhere method:

```php
Model::where('votes', '>', 100)
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'abcd')
                ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('name', 'cdef')
                        ->where('votes', '>', 50);
                });
        })
        ->get();
```

The example above will produce the following SQL:

```php
select * from `users` where `votes` > 100 or (`name` = "abcd" or (`name` = "cdef" and `votes` > 50));
```

**Mutipal where with whereNot and orWhereNot method**

- The whereNot and orWhereNot methods may be used to negate a given group of query constraints. For example, the following query excludes products that are on clearance or which have a price that is less than ten:

```php
$products = Product::where([
        ['status', '=', '1'],
        ['is_feature', '1']
    ])
        ->whereNot(function ($query) {
            $query->where('clearance', true)
                ->orWhere('price', '<', 10);
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')->where([['title','like','%'.$input.'%'],
    ['status','<>','Pending'],
    ['status','<>','Not Available']])
->orwhere([['owner', 'like', '%'.$input.'%'],
    ['status','<>','Pending'],
    ['status','<>','Not Available']])->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to apply any other filters to sub queries, otherwise the or might gather all records.

```
$query = Activity::whereNotNull('id');
$count = 0;
foreach ($this->Reporter()->get() as $service) {
        $condition = ($count == 0) ? "where" : "orWhere";
        $query->$condition(function ($query) use ($service) {
            $query->where('branch_id', '=', $service->branch_id)
                  ->where('activity_type_id', '=', $service->activity_type_id)
                  ->whereBetween('activity_date_time', [$this->start_date, $this->end_date]);
        });
    $count++;
}
return $query->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

With Eloquent it is easy to create multiple where check:

First: (Use simple where)

```
$users = User::where('name', $request['name'])
    ->where('surname', $request['surname'])
    ->where('address', $request['address'])
    ...
    ->get();
```

Second: (Group your where inside an array)

```
$users = User::where([
    ['name', $request['name']],
    ['surname', $request['surname']],
    ['address', $request['address']],
    ...
])->get();
```

You can also use conditional (=, <>, etc.) inside where like this:

```
$users = User::where('name', '=', $request['name'])
    ->where('surname', '=', $request['surname'])
    ->where('address', '<>', $request['address'])
    ...
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use in several ways,

```php
$results = User::where([
    ['column_name1', '=', $value1],
    ['column_name2', '<', $value2],
    ['column_name3', '>', $value3]
])->get();
```

You can also use like this,

```php
$results = User::orderBy('id','DESC');
$results = $results->where('column1','=', $value1);
$results = $results->where('column2','<',  $value2);
$results = $results->where('column3','>',  $value3);
$results = $results->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

As per my suggestion if you are doing filter or searching

then you should go with :

```
        $results = User::query();
        $results->when($request->that, function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('that', $request->that);
        });
        $results->when($request->this, function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('this', $request->that);
        });
        $results->when($request->this_too, function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('this_too', $request->that);
        });
        $results->get();
```

Comment: does the searching happen in the phpside or sql side?

Comment: Sql side. Sql query execute as request parameter. ex. if requrst has this param. Then where this = '' where condition added to query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use eloquent in **Laravel 5.3**

All results

```
UserModel::where('id_user', $id_user)
                ->where('estado', 1)
                ->get();
```

Partial results

```
UserModel::where('id_user', $id_user)
                    ->where('estado', 1)
                    ->pluck('id_rol');
```

Comment: How is this different from the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use array in where clause as shown in below.

```
$result=DB::table('users')->where(array(
'column1' => value1,
'column2' => value2,
'column3' => value3))
->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', '=', 'John')
            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                      ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('votes', '>', 100)
                    ->orWhere('name', 'John')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

A sample of code.

Firstly :

```
$matchesLcl=[];
```

array gets filled here  using desired count / loop of **conditions, incremently :**

```
 $matchesLcl['pos']= $request->pos;
$matchesLcl['operation']= $operation;
//+......+
$matchesLcl['somethingN']= $valueN;
```

and further with eloquents like this shrink expression  :

```
if (!empty($matchesLcl))
    $setLcl= MyModel::select(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
        ->where($matchesLcl)
        ->whereBetween('updated_at', array($newStartDate . ' 00:00:00', $newEndDate . ' 23:59:59'));
else 
    $setLcl= MyModel::select(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
        ->whereBetween('updated_at', array($newStartDate . ' 00:00:00', $newEndDate . ' 23:59:59'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Eloquent, implement it like so. This code returns all logged in users whose accounts are active. 
  `$users = \App\User::where('status', 'active')->where('logged_in', true)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

if your conditionals are like that (matching a single value), a simple more elegant way would be:

```
$results = User::where([
         'this' => value,
         'that' => value,
         'this_too' => value,
          ...
      ])
    ->get();
```

but if you need to OR the clauses then make sure for each orWhere() clause you repeat the must meet conditionals.

```
    $player = Player::where([
            'name' => $name,
            'team_id' => $team_id
        ])
        ->orWhere([
            ['nickname', $nickname],
            ['team_id', $team_id]
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

We use this instruction to obtain users according to two conditions, type of user classification and user name.

Here we use two conditions for filtering as you type in addition to fetching user information from the profiles table to reduce the number of queries.

```
$users = $this->user->where([
                    ['name','LIKE','%'.$request->name.'%'],
                    ['trainers_id','=',$request->trainers_id]
                    ])->with('profiles')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as following, which is the shortest way.

```
    $results = User::where(['this'=>1, 
              'that'=>1, 
               'this_too'=>1, 
               'that_too'=>1, 
              'this_as_well'=>1, 
               'that_as_well'=>1, 
                'this_one_too'=>1, 
               'that_one_too'=>1, 
              'this_one_as_well'=>1,
                'that_one_as_well'=>1])->get();
```

Answer (score -5):

```
public function search()
{
    if (isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET))
    {
        $prepareQuery = '';
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $data)
        {
            if ($data)
            {
                $prepareQuery.=$key . ' = "' . $data . '" OR ';
            }
        }
        $query = substr($prepareQuery, 0, -3);
        if ($query)
            $model = Businesses::whereRaw($query)->get();
        else
            $model = Businesses::get();

        return view('pages.search', compact('model', 'model'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score -7):

In Eloquent you can try this:

```
$results = User::where('this', '=', 1)
->orWhere('that', '=', 1)
->orWhere('this_too', '=', 1)
->orWhere('that_too', '=', 1)
->orWhere('this_as_well', '=', 1)
->orWhere('that_as_well', '=', 1)
->orWhere('this_one_too', '=', 1)
->orWhere('that_one_too', '=', 1)
->orWhere('this_one_as_well', '=', 1)
->orWhere('that_one_as_well', '=', 1)
->get();
```

Answer (score -35):

```
$variable = array('this' => 1,
                    'that' => 1
                    'that' => 1,
                    'this_too' => 1,
                    'that_too' => 1,
                    'this_as_well' => 1,
                    'that_as_well' => 1,
                    'this_one_too' => 1,
                    'that_one_too' => 1,
                    'this_one_as_well' => 1,
                    'that_one_as_well' => 1);

foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
    User::where($key, '=', $value);
}
```

Comment: This will execute multiple queries.