# Using a single array to pass multiple WHERE conditions (with LIKE)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-clause, sql-like

### Theory

[It's been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/laravel-eloquent-multiple-where) that one can use the following code to pass multiple `WHERE` clauses to single `where()` method in Laravel's Eloquent:

```
$condition = array('field_1' => 'value_1', 'field_2' => 'value_2');
$users = User::where($conditon)->get();
```

The code above simply chains the array's key-value pairs with `AND`, generating this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE field_1 = value_1 AND field_2 = value_2;
```

### Problem

The key-value pairs above base on equality. **Is it possible to use the same implementation for strings, where instead of `=` we use `LIKE`?**

Abstract example of what I mean:

```
$condition = array(
                array('field_1', 'like', '%value_1%'),
                array('field_2', 'like', '%value_2%')
             );
$users = User::where($conditon)->get();
```

This can for sure be done with multiple `->where(...)` usage. Is it doable with passing a single array, though?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No not really. But internally Laravel just does it with a loop as well.

`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder@where`

```
if (is_array($column))
{
    return $this->whereNested(function($query) use ($column)
    {
        foreach ($column as $key => $value)
        {
            $query->where($key, '=', $value);
        }
    }, $boolean);
}
```

I suggest you do something like this:

```
$condition = array(
                'field_1' => '%value_1%',
                'field_2' => '%value_2%'
             );

$users = User::where(function($q) use ($condition){
    foreach($condition as $key => $value){
        $q->where($key, 'LIKE', $value);
    }
})->get();
```

Comment: That, indeed, looks like the only way to currently do it the Laravel way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the edit, copy pasted a bit to fast ;)

Comment: Just to add incase this happens to someone else, make sure you add % around the value as it won't work otherwise!

Comment: One can also use orWhere if they want OR instead of AND in the query