# How to use AND and where caluse in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Hey guys I am facing some problem I am using laravel 5.2 and I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Chat
WHERE (From='1234' AND Number='420') OR WHERE (From='420' AND Number='1234');
```

For that I am trying this but not getting the exact result:

```
    $products = Chat::where('from', '=', $from)->where('number', '=', $number)->orwhere('from', '=', $number)->orwhere('number', '=', $from)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```

How can I make it work there is no such document where I can generate a query like that.

Comment: use \DB::select("SELECT * FROM Chat
WHERE (From='1234' AND Number='420') OR WHERE (From='420' AND Number='1234')");

Comment: This question has a good answer to what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/laravel-eloquent-multiple-where-clause-query

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
$products = Chat::where([
['from', '=', $from],
['number', '=', $number],
])->orwhere([
['from', '=', $number],
['number', '=', $from],
])->get();
```

with reference from here : [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/laravel-eloquent-multiple-where-clause-query)