# orWhere issues in search

Tags: php, search, laravel-5, where-clause

Hi am searching my dashboard features

- CATALOGUE STYLES
- SAVED STYLES

The catalogue style is working perfectly but the saved style is searching based on the user, is there a way where is a andWhere() to search where(something) and where(another thing) in laravel.

```
public function search(){

    $wsSearch = Input::get('search');

    $term = $wsSearch;

    // search catalogue style

    $searchedCatalogueStylesCount = Cataloguestyle::where('catalogue_style_name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_style_description','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_sub_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->count();

    $searchedCatalogueStyles = Cataloguestyle::where('catalogue_style_name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_style_description','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_sub_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->paginate(50);

    // search saved style

    $searchedSaveStylesCount = Savestyle::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->orWhere('catalogue_style_name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_style_description','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_sub_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->count();

    $searchedSaveStyles = Savestyle::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->orWhere('catalogue_style_name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_style_description','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->orWhere('catalogue_sub_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
    ->paginate(50);

    Session::flash('searchTerm',$term);

    // return Redirect::to('/search')
    return view('main_app.dashboard.search')
    ->with(['searchedCatalogueStyles' => $searchedCatalogueStyles,
            'searchedSaveStyles' => $searchedSaveStyles,
            'searchedCatalogueStylesCount' => $searchedCatalogueStylesCount,
            'searchedSaveStylesCount' => $searchedSaveStylesCount
            ]);

}
```

If you look closely at the `$searchedSaveStyles` variable, you will see `where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)`, we want it to be a and the following where statements not or, how do we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it so that all the OR WHERE's are grouped then you would put them inside a WHERE with a function, like so:

```
$searchedSaveStyles = Savestyle::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
  ->where(function($q) {
    $q->orWhere('catalogue_style_name','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
      ->orWhere('catalogue_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
      ->orWhere('catalogue_style_description','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')
      ->orWhere('catalogue_sub_categories','LIKE','%'.$term.'%');
  })->paginate(50);
```

Comment: this is what it gave me syntax error, unexpected '}',by the way this is what i am trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/laravel-eloquent-multiple-where-clause-query?rq=1

Comment: I forgot a ';', try it now

Comment: Thanks @Sane "i love you" for this.