# laravel 5 query multiple constraint on eager load

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my controller I have following code:

```
//Example Data;
$date = Carbon::now();
$order = 'name'; // it can be by name, id or created_at;

// Approach i try for getting data of user with eager loaded products

//1st approach
$user = User::with([
    'products' => function ($query) use ($date, $order) {
        $query->where('created_at', $date)->orderBy($order, 'desc');
    },
])->get();

//2nd approach
$user = User::with([
    'products' => function ($query) use ($date, $order) {
        $query->where('created_at', $date);
        $query->orderBy($order, 'desc');
    },
])->get();
```

On both approach, only the **1st condition** of the query is being read.

I want to make **1** `where()` clause and **1** `orderBy` to be filtered in the eager loaded data.

Is there something i miss out doing? Do I code it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: @Veerendra nope, please read the title carefully.

Comment: First thing your first and second approach makes the same sense just the pattern to write is different. Second you have not even tried the second where clause in both approach. Please post the code with what you have tried for the second where clause. Please refer the example $users = User::with(array(
    'posts' => function($query, $title) { $query->where('title', '=', $title); },
    'posts.tags' => function($query) { $query->where('tag_type', '=', 'admin') }
))->get();

Comment: Typo error, done updated. Also, you example code looks different for what i want to achieve.

Comment: Is $date a Carbon or DateTime object? And what is $order? You can order by some column of the table.

Comment: @AlexLukinov added example data for $date and $order.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's alright. Maybe try to add `'='` in `where` and `orderBy`

Comment: @AlexLukinov won't work :/

Comment: This should work 100%. Can you check your MySQL log or the raw SQL to confirm what query is being built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issue by adding a closure to the `where()` condition.

```
$user = User::with([
    'products' => function ($query) use ($date, $order) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($date, $order) {
            $q->where('created_at', $date); //This can accept more where() condition
        })->orderBy($order,'DESC');
    }])->get();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using nested eager loading. Some thing like:

```
$user = User::with([
    'products' => function ($query) use ($date) {
            $query->where('created_at', $date);
        },'products.order' =>function ($query) use ($order) {
            $query->orderBy($order, 'desc');
        } 
    ])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that your orderBy is being made at the "subquery". When laravel does the [join](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/join-syntax/) (that's what an eager loading is), the order_by will not be relevant to you.

I think an useful solution would be using the orderby clause outside the query, using the alias provided by laravel.

`$user = User::with([
        'products' => function ($query) use ($date, $order) {
            $query->where('created_at', $date)->orderBy($order, 'desc');
        },
    ])->orderBy("$laravel_join_generated_alias.$order", 'desc')->get();`

where the `$laravel_join_generated_alias` you could use the [debugbar](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-debugbar) to check how this string will work.

Answer (score 2):

As your description, both approaches **should** work well.

Are there some scopes which use `->orderBy()` in your `User` Model so the `orderBy()` in with closure is confused.

`dd($query->toSql())` in with closure maybe helpful to you.