# How use use multi compare with one where() in laravel eloquent query?

Tags: php, laravel, select, eloquent, laravel-5

In laravel elequent query how to make these two where select in one.

I also feels if there too many conditions, I've too use too many where clause.

```
->where('trade_status', '<>', 'TRADE_FINISHED')
->where('trade_status', '<>', 'TRADE_SUCCESS')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: yes, it is already answered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereNotIn()`:

```
->whereNotIn('trade_status', ['TRADE_FINISHED', 'TRADE_SUCCESS']);
```

Comment: Yeah! great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) you can notice

You can pass array of condition like

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status', '=', '1'],
    ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();
```

for your condition it should be like

```
 DB::table('your_table')->where([
    ['trade_status', '<>', 'TRADE_FINISHED'],
    ['trade_status', '<>', 'TRADE_SUCCESS'],
])->get();
```

Comment: here if i can omit the = character?

Comment: yes, use a simple where, the = can be omitted like this where(
    'status', '1'), I will checked is it ok in the complex where.

Comment: yes, there are a few ways you can do it  as documentation shows .