# Laravel eloquent select data only specific term

Tags: php, laravel

I have a data table with several status condition.
For example:
`status = "pending","approved","rejected"`.

How to use eloquent query to select the column for status "pending", "rejected" only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select data where status is `pendning` or `rejected`, use `whereIn()`:

```
Model::whereIn('status', ['pending', 'rejected'])->get();
```

Or `orWhere()`:

```
Model::where('status', 'pending')->orWhere('status', 'rejected')->get();
```