# How can I avoid Eloquent query to be chained?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel.

I wonder how I can avoid query to be chained.

```
$visitRecords = VisitRecord::whereDate('visited_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());


$knockBounce = $visitRecords->where("bounce_zone", "1")->get()->count();


$approachBounce = $visitRecords->where("bounce_zone", "2")->get()->count();
```

This is the code I wrote but this gives me the result I don't expect...

## Result

```
select * from `visit_records` where date(`visited_at`) = '2017-05-12' 

select * from `visit_records` where date(`visited_at`) = '2017-05-12' and `bounce_zone` = '1'

select * from `visit_records` where date(`visited_at`) = '2017-05-12' and `bounce_zone` = '1' and `bounce_zone` = '2'
```

I checked the query conducted and this is what I got.

## What I expect...

```
select * from `visit_records` where date(`visited_at`) = '2017-05-12' 

select * from `visit_records` where date(`visited_at`) = '2017-05-12' and `bounce_zone` = '1'

select * from `visit_records` where date(`visited_at`) = '2017-05-12' and `bounce_zone` = '2'
```

I want to conduct this query instead via Eloquent methods.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27522556/6140684) - are you sure it is chained? it shouldn't

Comment: I got these sql query from debugbar console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only instantiated a single `QueryBuilder` object.

You should create a second `QueryBuilder` object for the second query.

```
//Only create one carbon object
$date = Carbon::today()->toDateString()

$knockBounce = VisitRecord::whereDate('visited_at', '=', $date)->where("bounce_zone", "1")->count();

$approachBounce = VisitRecord::whereDate('visited_at', '=', $date)->where("bounce_zone", "2")->count();
```

Updated as per Matthew's comment, Laravel will execute a `->get()` anyway for aggregate functions (`count`, `min`, `max`, `avg`) under the hood so it's not needed.

Comment: You should use directly ->count() without ->get() :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two different `objects`

you might try below code

```
$visitRecords = VisitRecord::whereDate('visited_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());

$visitRecords1 = clone $visitRecords;    

$knockBounce = $visitRecords->where("bounce_zone", "1")->get()->count();    

$approachBounce = $visitRecords1->where("bounce_zone", "2")->get()->count();
```

Here I have used `clone` to copy the `$visitRecords` object

Further reading about [php clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score -1):

Edit to take only the needed bounce_zone

Alternatively, you can use collections :

```
$visitRecords = VisitRecord::whereDate('visited_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->where("bounce_zone", "1")->orWhere("bounce_zone", "2")->get();


$knockBounce = $visitRecords->where("bounce_zone", "1")->count();


$approachBounce = $visitRecords->where("bounce_zone", "2")->count();
```

You run only one query and use all the power of Laravel :)

Comment: Run query once but at what cost? Depends on business logic but I'd avoid fetching data you don't intend to process. e.g. all the records `where bounce_zone not in (1, 2)` could be millions of rows you never need ?

Comment: @luke does this approach require more calculations?

Comment: This answer also uses the Collection version of `where()`, which could end up being extremely slow.

Comment: @Hayatomo Not more calculations but potentially returns values in the collection you will never need. If you have other values than `1` or `2` for `bounce_zone` they will be returned in the `$visitRecords` collection but just sit there until the collection was removed by garbage collector as they wouldn't be used in `$knockBounce` or `$approachBounce`