# Laravel collection multiple where conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Following this post [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

I am trying to insert multiple 'and' conditions:

```
$matchThese = ['destination.country' => 'china', 'doc.description' => 'business'];

    return $collection->where($matchThese);
```

but I receive this error:

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::where(), 1 passed . . . but two expected
```

Comment: where expects two parameters, you could probably do something like this return $collection->where($matchThese[0], $matchThese[1]);

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Collection `where` method doesn't accept an array of conditions like eloquent does. But you can chain multiple where conditions.

```
return $collection->where('destination.country', 'china')
    ->where('doc.description', 'business');
```

Example

```
$data = [
    ['name' => 'john', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com'],
    ['name' => 'john', 'email' => 'jim@gmail.com'],
    ['name' => 'kary', 'email' => 'kary@gmail.com'],
];

$collection = collect($data);

$result = $collection->where('name', 'john');
// [{"name":"john","email":"john@gmail.com"},{"name":"john","email":"jim@gmail.com"}]


$result = $collection->where('name', 'john')->where('email', 'john@gmail.com');
// [{"name":"john","email":"john@gmail.com"}]
```

Comment: Seeing how similar Collections are to Eloquent this is not obvious from the Laravel documentations. Thanks!

Comment: this is true for and condition

Answer (score 10):

Chaining multiple `where`s will surely work, but you will do a loop for each one of them. Use [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter) instead. That will loop through and check for all your conditions only once.

```
$matchThese = ['destination.country' => 'china', 'doc.description' => 'business'];

return $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($matchThese) {
    foreach ($matchThese as $key => $value) {
        if ($item[$key] !== $value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `where` expects or needs more then one parameter, it does not work.

That is what your error says:

> Too few arguments to function where(), 1 passed . . . but two expected

You could probably do something like this:

```
return $collection->where($matchThese[0], $matchThese[1]);
```

Or this

```
return $collection->where($matchThese[0], OPERATOR, $matchThese[1]); // OPERATOR could be `=` or `<>`
```

So to have multiple where conditions one can do something like this:

```
return $collection->where($matchThese[0], $matchThese[1])
                  ->where($foo, $bar);
```

you can basically just chain them.

Comment: He was searching for an answer to have multiple where conditions, not the correct input format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this issue:

```
    $matchThese = ['country' => 'china', 'description' => 'business'];
    $data = collect([...]);
    $query = null;

    foreach ($matchThese as $col => $value) {
        $query = ($query ?? $data)->where($col, $value);
    }
```

At the end of the loop, `$query` will contain the results.