# SQL query to Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-5.5

to implement a basic relationship system I followed this model suggested from a website:

```
user_relationship:
------------------
- user_1
- user_2
- status
- user_action
```

Where `user_1`, `user_2`, `user_action` are foreign keys that references `users.id` and `user_1 < user_2` to avoid duplicate tuples.

However I'm finding it difficult to write this SQL query in Eloquent (Laravel 5.5):

```
SELECT user_1, user_2
FROM user_relationships
WHERE (user_1 = :user OR user_2 = :user) AND status = 'friends'
```

This query should return all the tuples where user is either `user_1` or `user_2`.

I have a very basic knowledge of Eloquent so I'm having a hard time making this work, but since I've seen many people saying that it's better to use Eloquent whenever possible I'd like to use it.

Comment: Stop using the old JOIN methode what is over 25 years old. use `INNER JOIN {table] ON [statements]` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do in wrong way. Better solution is to use relations in model.
You can make relations such as:

- One To One
- One To Many
- Many To Many
- Has Many Through
- Polymorphic Relations
- Many To Many Polymorphic Relations

This will save your time, read it:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: In fact I asked how to write this SQL Query using Eloquent. I thought about using `hasMany()` on the `User` model but I don't know how to say that user can be either `user_1` or `user_2` and using `hasMany()` two times with two different foreign keys seems a bit stupid.

Comment: I would make two tables: 'users' and 'users_relations'. In 'users_relation' i would make four columns: 'id', 'first_user_id', 'second_user_id', 'relation_type'. I know that it is not direct answer, but in my opinion you need to change approach to eloquent.

Comment: I probably didn't explain myself, sorry. That is exactly what I have, two tables - `users` and `user_relationships` - and `user_relationships` has 4 main columns (apart from `id` and timestamps): `user_1`, `user_2`, `status` and `user_action` which is the user that caused last change in status. However I cannot achieve what I want with a single `hasMany("App\UserRelationship", "user_1")` because the user could also be in `user_2`. I could run two queries with `hasMany()` and `user_1`/`user_2` as foreign keys and then merge the results but I was looking for a better solution

Comment: In that case i would propose to use 'orWhere' in your query. Select all rows if user is in this or this column. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent