# Display from database if 2 columns match

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and am currently I am working on a very basic private messaging system.

Currently I am trying to display a page which shows the messages between 2 users (sent and received), however I am only able to display the messages which the user has sent. Here is my viewMessage function in my MessageController file.

**MessageController.php**

```
public function viewMessage($recipient_id){

    $user = auth()->user()->id;

    $messages = Message::where('sender_id', $user)->where('recipient_id', $recipient_id)->get();

    return view ('pages.messages.view', compact('user', 'messages'));
}
```

**View Blade**

```
<ul>

    @foreach ($messages as $message)

        <li>{{$message->body}}</li>

    @endforeach

</ul>
```

As you can see from the $messages variable, i have a query builder which should match the sender ID with the ID of the current logged in user. It should also match the recipient ID with the ID of the user from the parameter, however this does not currently work.

I have used `dd()` and both sender id and recipient id is coming through correctly so I am at a loss as to why this is not working. I am assuming I am probably using the query builder incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: use `dd()` for `$messages`, also try to remove the second `where` and see if you'll get any different result.

Comment: The only thing that I can see in this code that might be going wrong is the chained `where` clauses. You can add an array into a single `where` and see if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent . Other than that, it must be how you've saved your data because the posted code looks fine --> the data you want to retrieve simply isn't there.

Comment: @Loek definitely I could see that the code looks right as well, and chained `where()` clause adds an `and` to the query

Comment: Yeah that's what I remembered as well. Then that means the requested data either isn't in the database, or it's saved wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only asking for messages the user sent. You need to also get messages that the user received.

```
$user = auth()->user()->id;

$messages = Message::where('sender_id', $user)->where('recipient_id', $recipient_id)->get();

$receivedMessages= Message::where('sender_id', recipient_id)->where('recipient_id', $user)->get();
```