# How to convert SQL query to PHP and use AND operator in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, operators

I have the php query below where I want to count how many times the `id` exist in a column

```
$empCount = DB::table('m_employee')->count('group_id')->where('group_id',$idHolder);
```

**VALUES**

```
//tblname is m_employee; column name is group_id and my search variable is $idHolder
```

Error message is:

> {"message":"Call to a member function where() on integer",.......

[image]

For this sample, when the value of my `$idHolder` is 1, the result of `$empCount` should be `13`, if it's 2, result is `3`.
And after that, how can I use `AND` operator from this query :

```
DB::table('emp')->where('key',  $emp)->update([
   'id' => $id,
]);
```

Like `where('key',  $emp) AND ('monthyear', '06/2018')`, basing the date from the `cost_date` column above (extracting only the month and year) .I'm having hard time on where to insert it.

Comment: @user3783243 Updated. Apologies for not explaining well, what I'm referring with `id` means my `code` for a specific group name.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and what the output should be?

Comment: @user3783243 Please see update. Thanks.

Comment: You should use a `group by` and a `count` of each `id`. I'm not familiar with how that is done with larvel though. In regular SQL it'd be `select count(*), group_id from table where cost_date = ? group by group_id` (...assuming I'm reading what you want correctly)

Comment: @downvoter Mind pointing some notes on where I need to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the query below for the count

`$empCount = DB::table('m_employee')->where('group_id',$idHolder)->count();`

For the `AND` operator, you can simply chain the where clauses to simulate this

`DB::table('emp')->where('key',  $emp)->where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(cost_date,'%m-%Y'))"), '=', '06-2018')->update([
   'id' => $id,
]);`

Comment: Thanks for solving the count which works well. And can I extract a date that matches for my given month and year? Please see my sample table above. So if my date is 06/2018, it should match to `2018-06-18` column. Thanks,

Comment: Updated my answer above, you can try it.

Comment: MMM, there's an error saying `unxpected ','` I try to do: `DB::table('emp')->whereRaw("(DATE_FORMAT(monthyear,'%m/%Y'))"), '=', '06/2018')->update([
   'id' => $id,
]);` Thanks.

Comment: I think it's not the problem, coz that works well on my other queries. So I try, `->whereRaw("(DATE_FORMAT(cost_date,'%m-%Y'))=",'06/2018')...`, error is `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;....`

Comment: If you use `%m-%Y`, you should use `06-2018` in the following parameter

Comment: The same error. Please take a look with my revisions, `...->whereRaw("(DATE_FORMAT(cost_date,'%Y-%m'))",'=', '2018-06')...` This is the line it is pointing  `'(DATE_FORMAT(cost_date,'%Y-%m'))'`

Comment: Maybe it's not working because I'm using Eloquent, that line is the only one that is giving an error.

Comment: It say's unknown column, but as I checked, it's already the correct column name.

Comment: Updated my answer above, there were extra parentheses that is causing the error

Comment: I have already changed that earlier, it gets back to my original error `Syntax error or access violation`. I have somewhat found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent) but I'm still trying to understand it.

Comment: Have you also tried fixing the parentheses of the where clause with the DB::raw? `where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(cost_date,'%m-%Y'))"), '=', '06-2018')`

Comment: That beat it! Finally :)

Comment: Way to go! I'll update my answer above as a reference for others :)