# How to update row based on two condition using eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sql-update

I have a table : Profile
Table has one foreign key and primary key. 
I want to update row based on two condition .
Like : where ( id == 1 and user == 'admin')

How to use two para meter in update query using eloquent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can do this by make the following:

```
ModelName::where(['id'=>1,'user'=>'admin'])
->update(['column_name'=>'value',.....]);
```

Comment: getting error - `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' `

Comment: Could you provide me with what you wrote ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$obj=ModelName::where('id','=',1)->where('user','=','admin')->first();
if(count($obj) == 1){
   $obj->column_name=value;
   $obj->save();
}
```

Comment: this just updates all rows with user = admin from my tests