# How to implement "where" clause with "and" condition in eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've googled for minutes and couldn't find an answer to my question.
I want to search users with a string that have certain characters in the name and have a specified id_admin.

I want this

```
 select * from users where name like '%searching name%' and id_admin = 300;
```

I am trying this

```
 $resultado = User::where("name", "like", '%'. $nome . '%')->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('id_admin', 300);
            })->get();
```

This is ignoring the 300

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$resultado = User::where([["name", "like", '%'. $nome . '%'],['id_admin', '300']])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$resultado = User::where("name", "like", '%'. $nome . '%')->where('id_admin', 300)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
$resultado = User::where('id_admin', 300)->where("name", "like", '%'. $nome . '%')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultado = User::where([
  ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
  ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
  [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
  ...
])
```