# How to use "or" with multiple "where" in Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I implement this in Eloquent?.

```
select * from product where name like '%value%' and (product_type = product_type_param or product_type_param = 0);
```

If a `product_type_param` value of `0` is supplied, it will select products of all types, taking into account that the name also matched, of course.

My current code:

```
$result = Product::where( [  ['name', 'like', '%' . 
$searchAttributes['name'] . '%'],
    ['product_type', '=', $searchAttributes['product_type']]]
     )->get();
```

The idea would be something like this (excuse the example, it only shows my intention):

```
 ['product_type', '=', $searchAttributes['product_type']] or [$searchAttributes['product_type'] == 0]]
```

Should I execute a raw query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple where clause query using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: I am using a static condition. That's what bugs me.

Comment: Is `product_type_param` a column or a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure function to scope the query

```
Product::where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchAttributes['name'] . '%')
        ->where(function($q) use ($searchAttributes) {
             $q->where('product_type', $searchAttributes['product_type'])
               ->orWhere('product_type_param', 0);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

using `orWhere`:

```
  Product::where([
       ['column','value'],
       ['another_column','value'],
   ])->orWhere([
      ['column','value']
   ])->get();
```