# Adding Multiple Where Clause from Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model

I am trying to clean my code up, and working on the Models

I have the following 2 tables broken down like this:

**Roll Table**

```
|id|roll_id|member_id|.......
```

**Members table**

```
|id|first_name|last_name|rank|
```

I have the following on my Roll Model

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
}
```

This on my Member model

```
public function roll()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Roll');
}
```

While the following code does return the correct results

```
$roll = Roll::with(['member'])
        ->where('status', '!=', 'A')
        ->get();

return ($roll);
```

I would like to add an extra where clause

```
->where('rank','<', 12)
```

However, I get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'member.rank'
>   in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Roll` where `roll_id` = 4 and
>   `status` != A and `mem ▶"

Comment: Did you tried whereHas?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522556/8677188)

Comment: @Ishann that post refers to 1 table, this is 2, the problem I face is it does find the member.rank column using the code provided above, the Roll::with(['member']) is returning the correct link between the 2 tables, and I can apply a where clause to the Roll Table, I can't to the member table as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` method to filter on the relations:

```
$roll = Roll::with(['member'])
    ->where('status', '!=', 'A')
    ->whereHas('member', function($query) {
        $query->where('members.rank', '<', 12);
    })
    ->get();
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - now know I need to refer to the table and not the model in the $query

Comment: You need to use the model name on which you are applying this condition.

Comment: Model name failed but table name worked, so for me member.rank failed (where member is the model), but members.rank worked (where members is the table name)

Comment: The first argument inside the whereHas method will be the name of the relation and while using it in that query it will be table name members.rank.

Comment: Is it possible to define this in the HTML blade view? I would like to pull all of my Roll and Count Officer Ranks (rank < 12), WO Rank (between 12,13), NCO rank (between 14, 18) Cadet (rank > 18). This will save me completing the code a number of times, thanks