# Laravel-5.6 'LIKE' in where select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I use this query and i get a error :

```
 $description = $request->get('description');
        if (!empty($description)){
        $description_query = Transcationhistorique::where(['sender_id' => $user_id, "%$description%", 'LIKE','description'])
            ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user_id)->get();
        }else{
            $description_query  =  "" ;
        }
```

and this is the error that I get :

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `transcation_historique` where
>   (`sender_id` = 32 and `0` = %salaire% and `1` = LIKE and `2` =
>   description) or `receiver_id` = 32)"

and this what really i want to run:

```
select * from `transcation_historique` where (`sender_id` = 32 and `description` = %salaire%) or `receiver_id` = 32)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$description_query = Transcationhistorique::where(
                         function($query) use ($user_id, $description){
                             return $query->where('sender_id', $user_id)
                                          ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $description .'%');

                         }
                     )
                     ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user_id)
                     ->get();
```

Comment: i always get all transaction

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting a not empty description?

Comment: I think for all the cases this condition is excuting and you are getting all transaction. `->orWhere('receiver_id', $user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your where query is not structured correctly.
You should use the following structure if you want to use operators other than "="
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

```
$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])
```

My suggestion is:

```
 $description = $request->get('description');
 if (!empty($description)){
     $description_query = Transcationhistorique::where([
            ['sender_id', '=', $user_id],
            ['description', 'LIKE', "%{$description}%"]
     ])
     ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user_id)->get();
 }else{
     $description_query  =  "" ;
 }
```

Comment: i always get all transaction

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Transcationhistorique::where('receiver_id', '=', $user_id)
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user_id, $description) {
            $query->where('sender_id', '=', $user_id)->where('description', 'LIKE', "%".$description."%");
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `where` method as `and`.
Can you try following codes?

```
    $description = $request->get('description');
    if (!empty($description)){
        $description_query = Transcationhistorique::where('sender_id', $user_id)
        ->where("description", 'LIKE','%' . $description . '%')
        ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user_id)->get();
    }else{
        $description_query  =  "" ;
    }
```

Comment: Look at his manul query. where( multiple condition ) or where( single condition)

Comment: i always get all transaction

Comment: I can't understand you? I said that ``where`` "method can use much times".

Comment: Just i don't get the empty description rows but i get all my rows

Comment: If you want using two ``and`` one ``or`` criteria on your query. My solution will work.

Comment: You may should need use for like ``orWhere`` instead of ``where``. Sorry i can't understand your problem. If you tell me  your all needs, i can helpful.