# Laravel-5.6 'LIKE ' in where and or where select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I use this query and i get a error :

```
$description = $request->get('description');
                $description_query = Transcationhistorique::where(function ($query) use ($description, $user_id) {
                    $query->where('receiver_id', $user_id,'description', 'LIKE','%' . $description . '%')
                        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE','%' . $description . '%','sender_id', $user_id);
                })->get();
```

and this is the error that I get :

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `transcation_historique` where
>   (`sender_id` = 32 and `0` = %salaire% and `1` = LIKE and `2` =
>   description) or `receiver_id` = 32)"

and this what really i want to run:

```
select * from `transcation_historique` where (`sender_id` = 32 and `description` = %salaire%) or (`receiver_id` = 32 and `description` = %salaire%)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel-5.6 'LIKE' in where select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883894/laravel-5-6-like-in-where-select)

Comment: is my other question

Comment: is not the same

Comment: I want to point that the select you want as result is the same with a condition added: so **The problem to solve is the same**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$description = $request->get('description');
$query = Transcationhistorique::where(function ($query) use ($description, $user_id) {
      $query->where('receiver_id', $user_id)
          ->where('description', 'LIKE','%' . $description . '%');
})
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($description, $user_id) {
      $query->where('sender_id', $user_id)
          ->where('description', 'LIKE','%' . $description . '%');
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
Transcationhistorique::where(function ($query) use ($description, $user_id) {
            $query->where(['receiver_id' => $user_id, 'description' => 'LIKE %' . $description . '%'])
                ->orWhere(['description' => 'LIKE %' . $description . '%', 'sender_id' => $user_id]);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use the following statement:

```
$query = Transcationhistorique::where(function ($query) use ($description, $user_id) {
      $query->where('receiver_id', $user_id)
          ->where('description', 'LIKE','%' . $description . '%');
})
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($description, $user_id) {
      $query->where('sender_id', $user_id)
          ->where('description', 'LIKE','%' . $description . '%');
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try This with Query Builder :

```
$description_query = DB::table('transcationhistoriques')
            ->where(['receiver_id' => $user_id, 'description' => 'LIKE %' . $description . '%'])
            ->orWhere(['description' => 'LIKE %' . $description . '%', 'sender_id' => $user_id])
            ->get();
```