# How to use Laravel with 3 where clause in function?

Tags: laravel

i have a function to show data with 3 where clause condition . but this output is invalid . i have 4 data and just show 1 . this function like this :

```
public function alkes_user()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $unit        = User::where('roles_id' , 1)->pluck('nama_unit', 'id'); 


    $alat    = Alat::with('users')
    ->where('jenis' ,'Alkes')
    ->where('user_id',  $user_id)
    ->where('is_active',  'true')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('users.alkes_user',['alat' => $alat , 'unit' => $unit ,'count' => $count ]);
}
```

this data only showing 1 , but in database i have so many data . what wrong and how to solve this  ? thanks you

Comment: Your query is correct. Show your table data.

Comment: if i remove 1 where clause , its can showing full data . l

Comment: is jenis column in your users table? Please share your users table data

Comment: gives us more information where and how the data are stored on DB or you can simply solve this using `orWhere` method If any of the three `where` condition can be true since chaining `where` will be using 'AND'

Comment: I guess you want to filter `or`, can u explain what results do u want?

Comment: u mean its need OrWhere ?

Comment: Yes use `orWhere` if any of the three `where` condition can be true to fetch the rows

Comment: or u can post the example datas, and post what the real result is.

Comment: hope this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent

Comment: sir , its three where its same as if i using orWhere ? i miss perception on this . using where  = orWhere ?

Comment: chaining only `where` will generate the SQL query using `AND` while using `orWhere` it will generate the query using `OR`. You can use `toSql()` method to check what type of query is being generated too

Comment: So i need chaining only where on three clause . not OrWhere .its make different what i want to do

Comment: The important thing is what result you really want, may be orWhere cannot help u.plz explain what datas do u want from database?

Comment: The question is: what are you trying to achieve? We can not help you if we do not understand the issue. First you get the id of the current user, then you query the `User` model (without using `$user_id`), and then you query the `Alat` model with a query like `"...WHERE jenis='Alkes' AND user_id=$user_id AND is_active='true' ORDER BY created_at DESC"`. Note that here you are using `true` as a string. Is all this on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query like this if you want multiple where condition:

```
public function alkes_user(){
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $unit = User::where('roles_id' , 1)->pluck('nama_unit', 'id');
    $alat    = Alat::with('users')
                ->where([['jenis' ,'Alkes'],['user_id',  $user_id],['is_active',  'true']])
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('users.alkes_user',['alat' => $alat , 'unit' => $unit ,'count' => $count ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

```
$alat= Alat::with(array('users' => function($query) {
    $query->where([['jenis' ,'Alkes'],['user_id',  $user_id],[is_active',  'true']]);
}))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$unit = User::where('roles_id' , 1)->pluck('nama_unit', 'id');
$alat = Alat::with('users')->where([
        ['jenis' ,'=','Alkes'],
        ['user_id','=',$user_id],
        ['is_active','=','true']       
])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
return view('users.alkes_user',['alat' => $alat , 'unit' => $unit ,'count' => $count ]);
```