# how to remove unwanted values form array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, associative-array

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this kind of array? I only want this below part. I need to remove those mysql connection and other unwanted arrays from this.

```
array (
  'name' => 'Westwood',
  'id' => 538,
),
```

```
 0 => 
  Common\Models\Property::__set_state(array(
     'connection' => 'mysql',
     'table' => NULL,
     'primaryKey' => 'id',
     'keyType' => 'int',
     'incrementing' => true,
     'with' => 
    array (
    ),
     'perPage' => 15,
     'exists' => true,
     'wasRecentlyCreated' => false,
     'attributes' => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Westwood',
      'id' => 538,
    ),
     'guarded' => 
    array (
      0 => '*',
    ),
  )),
```

The below code shows what I did to get that array. when I `Log::info($results);`

I get that array hope you understand my question.

```php
$properties = model::where('status', '=', 'Active')
                ->get();

if($jsonData->city !== "") {
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        if($property->city === $jsonData->city) {
            $results[] = $property;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `get()` it will return a laravel collection, not an array, if you want an array, you can use `toArray()` it would look like this:

```
$properties = prop_model::where('status', '=', 'Active')
                ->where('propertylive', '=', 'Yes')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

Comment: inside foreach i have array (`$filteredProperty[] = $property;`) and that array gives me the above array. i want to remove those mysql connection values from the array. do you know how to do it

Comment: As @Gamopo has explained in his anwers, you should use the `toArray()` method after calling `get()`. This converts the result from a collection object (as documented in the Laravel docs) to an associative array as you require. +1 OP

Answer (score 2):

Based on [get() manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

> The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection containing the
>   results where each result is an instance of the PHP stdClass object.
>   You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a
>   property of the object

it will return a laravel collection.

So use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray) to get Array

> The toArray method converts the collection into a plain PHP array. If
>   the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be
>   converted to arrays

Also specify filed names to narrow down your array as well:

```
$properties = prop_model::select('name','id')
                ->where(['status', '=', 'Active'],['propertylive', '=', 'Yes'])
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

Reference taken: [How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 1):

`get()` function returns collection. So as per Laravel Documentation you can use `toArray()` function

> The `toArray` method converts the collection into a plain PHP array. If the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be converted to arrays.

```
$properties = prop_model::where('status', '=', 'Active')
                ->where('propertylive', '=', 'Yes')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

[Laravel -> Collection -> toArray](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray)