# Multiple where clause, Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I try to do a query with 2 where clauses, but I get a bad response, not sure why.

```
$history = AnswerHistory::where('question_id', '=', $id)
     ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('answer_type', '!=', "skipped");
      })
      ->get();
```

For a specific `$id` in database I have 5 rows, 4 with `answer_type = 'skipped`, but the 5-one is `NULL`.

My response is null with this code, if I remove second where I get 5 items that includes `"skipped"` answers.

Wanted response is 1 row, where `answer_type != 'skipped'`.

PS. I also tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is, a varchar that is `null` is `null` and not a varchar with a value. So it can not be checked with `=` or `!=` 'string'. So you have to check if `answer_type` is != skipped or null

```
$history = AnswerHistory::where('question_id', '=', $id)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('answer_type', '!=', "skipped")
            ->orWhereNull('answer_type');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I actually tried this right now, and works, but I didn't know why, till now, thank you!

Comment: null is not a string so you can't check it with = or != in sql

Answer (score 2):

You can change your query for multiple where condition like this

```
$history = AnswerHistory::where([['question_id', '=', $id],['answer_type','<>','skipped']])
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
```

And replace `!=` with `<>`

I hope it's helpful

Comment: @Beusebiu you yourself told that you have 5 rows where 4 rows have skipped and the 5th one is NULL so in that case the answer is right man

Comment: I upload a img. with an example for id 146.  In my response I need only the ones that are not 'skipped' even if are null, with this code I get null..

Comment: @Beusebiu query is right but make sure that your $id variable has correct value and do try the query without any condition to check whether your model is working properly or not