# WhereNull in where array eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using the below eloquent:

```
  Book::selectRaw("name")
            ->where($bookWheres)
            ->with(['chapter'=>function ($query) use($chapterWheres)
            {
                $query->where($chapterWheres);
            }])
            ->get()->dd();
```

To set the `$bookWheres / $chapterWheres` I am pusing the array `['xx', '>=', '5']`. However for the `$chapterWhere` I also need to push similar to ['timestamp', 'is', 'null'] since it is going to check if  a timestamp column is null/empty.

`->whereNull('timestamp')` would usually work. However the where clause `['timestamp', 'is', 'null']` is a filter so it could just as well be `not null, >= or <=.`

Is it possbile to push "is null" into the array?

Laravel 7.

Comment: you have to make it dynamic? or is something that you have always to add to the array? i mean, can't you just use `$query->where($chapterWheres)->whereNull('timestamp')`?

Comment: Have to add it dynamic :(

Comment: and you can't just use variable? please try with `['timestamp', 'IS NULL', null]`

Comment: The where clause has 3 more arrays which also are dynamic. The timestamp can eather be (not null, null or >/< than). The above gave the following errror: General error: 1525 Incorrect TIMESTAMP value: 'IS NULL'. SQL:  select * from `chapters` where `chapters`.`id` in (2, 259) and (`timestamp` = IS NULL)

Comment: well with query builder works aha try using query()->where([...])

Answer (score 0):

[Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent/19327251)>
try this it would be work for you

```
Book::selectRaw("name")
        ->where([$bookWheres])
        ->with(['chapter'=>function ($query) use($chapterWheres)
        {
            $query->where([$chapterWheres]);
        }])
        ->get();
```