# Combination of where and where is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem code beneath this line does not work! How can I let this work? where ... orWhere  orWhere does filter but cumulates the queries. where ... where does not provide any result. Can someone help me?

```
$artworks = Artwork::where('category_id', $category)
    ->where('style_id', $style)
    ->where('technic_id', $technic)
    ->where('orientation', $orientation)
    ->get();
```

Here is the full code:

```
if (request()->category_id) {
                $category = request()->category_id;
            } else {
                $category = 0;
            }

            if (request()->style_id) {
                $style = request()->style_id;
            } else {
                $style = 0;
            }

            if (request()->technic_id) {
                $technic = request()->technic_id;
            } else {
                $technic = 0;
            }

            if (request()->orientation_id == 'vertical') {
                $orientation = 'vertical';
            } else if (request()->orientation_id == 'horizontal') {
                $orientation = 'horizontal';
            } else {
                $orientation = 0;
            }


            $artists = Artist::get();
            $artworks = Artwork::where('category_id', $category)
                ->where('style_id', $style)
                ->where('technic_id', $technic)
                ->where('orientation', $orientation)
                ->get();
            
            return view('frontend.index', compact('artworks', 'artists'));
```

Comment: by does not work do you mean it returns nothing, no data in the collection?

Comment: Thats totally true

Comment: are you getting data in `Artwork::where('orientation', $orientation)
                ->get();`

Comment: i think this query have no any data in your databse

Comment: you can try this method [How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent) though it is the same just passing conditions in array

Comment: @GijsMachielsen: IF orWhere is returning the result then I think the combination of this doesn't match with database resulting in 0 results, can you please check if the database contains any record which matches against each where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `OR` Condition and you are mistaking it with double where. Please look below to understand properly

If you want `AND` condition in your query then the double where are used but if you want `OR` condition then you have to use `orWhere`

Examples:

`AND` condition

```
Query::where(condition)->where(condition)->get();
```

`OR` Conditon

```
Query::where(condition)->orWhere(condition)->get();
```

Comment: I want the And and statement. If I do this ```$artworks = Artwork::where('category_id', $category)->get()``` it will provide results  or this ```$artworks = Artwork::where('style_id', $style)->get()```or if I do this ```$artworks = Artwork::where('technic_id', $technic)->get()```. But if all want to combine them via this query :             ```$artworks = Artwork::where('category_id', $category)->where('style_id', $style)->where('technic_id', $technic)->get()```;
 then it is not working

Comment: Does anyone have an idea why I have no result with where where where?

Comment: presumably, they have not debugged the issue, because the query is correct. Since they're getting `_id` variables from the post request, they should first name the variables as such, i.e `category_id` instead of `category` then make sure that they are all set before the query. I will bet that one or more are not. Defaulting them to `0` is a really bad idea...

Comment: also, this suggests that you can have duplicate rows in the table, which is a problem on its own, consider making a link table

Comment: also, why are you checking if all of your `ids` are true? `if (request()->style_id) {`

Answer (score 0):

**If you expect all of your variables to be set**

Your query variables `category_id`, `style_id`, `orientation_id` & `technic_id` are being defaulted to 0 if they are not true.

Your query is fine, but you may not have the data you think you do.

Run the following at the top of this function:

```
print_r($request->all());
exit;
```

**If all of your variables are optional**

very procedural, basic way to achieve this:

```
            $artists = Artist::get();
            $artworks = Artwork::where('id', '>', 0);

            $category_id = request()->input('category_id');
            if ($category_id != '') {
                $artworks->where('category_id', request()->category_id);
            }

            $style_id = request()->input('style_id');
            if ($style_id != '') {
                $artworks->where('style_id', request()->style_id);
            }

            $technic_id = request()->input('technic_id');
            if ($technic_id != '') {
                $artworks->where('technic_id', request()->technic_id);
            }

            $orientation_id = request()->input('orientation_id');
            if ($orientation_id != '') {
                $artworks->where('orientation_id', request()->orientation_id);
            }

            $artworks->get();
            
            return view('frontend.index', compact('artworks', 'artists'));
```