# mysql query to laravel orm

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My goal is to convert the following SQL query to to Laravel query builder syntax,

```
    $qstA = "
            select sum(tmpbutbldata.Personnel_Hours_Spent) as PHS from tmpbutbldata 
            left join tbl_testlocation_links on tmpbutbldata.Test_Request_Number= tbl_testlocation_links.Test_Request_number 
            where 
            tmpbutbldata.Date_Test_Completed between '".$dateBack."' and '".$dateCurr."' 
            and tbl_testlocation_links.".$Location."='1' 
            and tmpbutbldata.type = '1' 
            and tmpbutbldata.cancelled = '0' 
            or 
            tmpbutbldata.Date_Test_Completed between '".$dateBack."' and '".$dateCurr."' 
            and tbl_testlocation_links.".$Location."='1' 
            and tmpbutbldata.type = '2' 
            and tmpbutbldata.cancelled = '0'"
    ;
```

what i've tried:

```
DB::table("tbldata")
        ->select(DB::raw('*'))
        ->leftJoin('tbl_testlocation_links', 'tbldata.Test_Request_Number', '=', 'tbl_testlocation_links.Test_Request_number')
        ->where(['Date_Test_Completed', '<', $dateBack],
                ['Date_Test_Completed', '>', $dateCurr],
                ['tbl_testlocation_links'.$location->TestLocation, '=', 1],
                ['type', '=', 1],
                ['cancelled', '=', 0])
        ->orWhere(['Date_Test_Completed', '<', $dateBack],
                ['Date_Test_Completed', '>', $dateCurr],
                ['tbl_testlocation_links'.$location->TestLocation, '=', 1],
                ['type', '=', 2],
                ['cancelled', '=', 0])
        ->get();
```

But I get the following error **ErrorException Array to string conversion**

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: on the **->get()** line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: Yup, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```php
DB::table("tbldata")
        ->select(DB::raw('*'))
        ->leftJoin('tbl_testlocation_links', 'tbldata.Test_Request_Number', '=', 'tbl_testlocation_links.Test_Request_number')
        ->where([
             ['Date_Test_Completed', '<', $dateBack],
             ['Date_Test_Completed', '>', $dateCurr],
             ['tbl_testlocation_links'.$location->TestLocation, '=', 1],
             ['type', '=', 1],
             ['cancelled', '=', 0]
        ])
        ->orWhere([
             ['Date_Test_Completed', '<', $dateBack],
             ['Date_Test_Completed', '>', $dateCurr],
             ['tbl_testlocation_links'.$location->TestLocation, '=', 1],
             ['type', '=', 2],
             ['cancelled', '=', 0]
        ])
        ->get();
```

Multiple conditions must be passed in a single where clause as an array of arrays, where each nested array represents a condition