# How to fetch two fields in table using where condition and how to apply like condition on it

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two fields in my table, contact_name and company. for searching purposes, I am using this. I need to search by using contact_name and company. Now one is working fine, but I need to add a second field in the same where condition. How do I add this?

```
if(isset($input['dsr_commonsearch']) && $input['dsr_commonsearch']){
        $query->where('dsr.contact_name','dsr.company','=', $input['dsr_commonsearch']); 
    }
```

Comment: What is `$query` ? the QueryBuilder?

Comment: if(isset($input['dsr_commonsearch']) && $input['dsr_commonsearch']){
            $query->where('dsr.contact_name','dsr.company','=', $input['dsr_commonsearch']); 
        }   this is our query two felids are contact_name and company     Hamza Abdaoui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using orWhere as below:

```
if(isset($input['dsr_commonsearch']) && $input['dsr_commonsearch']){
    $query->where('dsr.company','=', $input['dsr_commonsearch'])->orWhere('dsr.contact_name','=', $input['dsr_commonsearch']); 
}
```

Comment: is it working and how to add like instead of = because some times we will enter with sapce  
  Hamza Abdaoui

Comment: is it working and how to add like instead of = because some times we will enter with space  Zohaib Shah

Comment: @anu You can replace '=' with 'like' and in third argument append '%' in string