# How can I add "and" condition in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add another condition to `(L_Examen_Objectif::where('libelle', '=', $request->input('libelle') )->exists())`

The condition If I get the same **libelle** has the same **id** it should return `True` (I don't want to insert the same libelle with the same id.)

Here is it my code:

```
 public function addPost(Request $request, $id)
 {
     if (L_Examen_Objectif::where('libelle', '=', $request->input('libelle') )->exists()) {
         return  'true';
     }
     else {
         $Examen_data = array(
             'libelle' => $request->input('libelle'),
             'id_examen' => $request->input('id_examen'),
             'id_lexamen' => $id,
         );
         L_Examen_Objectif::insert($Examen_data);    
     }
 }
```

Comment: look here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in more ways than one. One solution would be:

```
L_Examen_Objectif::where([
   ['libelle', '=', $request->input('libelle')],
   ['other_key', '=', $request->input('libelle')],
  ])
```

This is the pattern for this way:

```
$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])
```

More Information you will find here: [How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)