# How to write double where with update in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

how to write like this. this function is not working for me

```
ContractorsServices::where('serviceID',$request->id)->where('isPopular', false)->update([
    'isPopular' => true
]);
```

Comment: Are you sure `$request->id` is correct? Run `dd($request->id)` before your query to make sure.

Comment: is the field ``isPopular`` updatable? Show the ContractorsServices model class.

Comment: See this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent

Comment: @OMiShah, he is running the database query directly and not "trough" Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

try doing it this way

```
ContractorsServices::where(['serviceID' => $request->id, 'isPopular' => 'false'])
->update([
    'isPopular' => true
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
ContractorsServices::where([
      ['serviceID',$request->id],
      ['isPopular', false]
    ])
    ->update([
       'isPopular' => true
    ]);
```

if not work, check data is correct or not:

```
$ContractorsServices = ContractorsServices::where([
  ['serviceID',$request->id],
  ['isPopular', false]
])->get();

 return $ContractorsServices;
```

Comment: it still dont works, response is [{"id":31,"contractorID":11,"serviceID":34,"price":1500,"isPopular":false,"relativePositionNumber":null,"comment":null,"updated_at":"2022-08-06T13:10:41.000000Z","created_at":"2022-08-05T06:21:10.000000Z"}]

Comment: maybe update is not working?

Comment: check `$ContractorsServices = ContractorsServices::where([
  ['serviceID',$request->id],
  ['isPopular', false]
])->get();

 return $ContractorsServices;`
if it is work and return data you can set `update()` instead `get()`, also you can get the data like first code in this comment and do this:
`foreach($ContractorsServices as $conser) { $conser->isPopular = false;  }`
after foreach `$ContractorsServices->save();`